# use a service to subscribe to the same data from multiple compontents

Tags: angular, mean-stack

There are several components in my angular5 app that need the products returned from a request to `/api/products`. Right now I am contacting the api for every component that needs product. How can I get the products in my service and then subscribe to the same data cross multiple components?

## in my components

```
    export class MiniSearchComponent implements OnInit {

        products: any;

        constructor(
            private bcProductService: BcProductService
        ) { this.onGetProducts(); }

        onGetProducts() {
            this.bcProductService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
                this.products = products.data;
            });
        }

    }
```

## In my Service

```
    getProducts() {
        return this.http.get<any>("/api/products");
    }
```

## My Attempt

**components**

```
    onGetProducts() {
        this.products = this.bcProductService.subscribeProducts();
    }
```

**service**

```
    products:any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.products = this.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
            console.log('products from service:', products);
            return products.data;
        });
    }

    getProducts() {
        return this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:3200/api/products");
    }

    subscribeProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**service**

```
products:any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
        console.log('products from service:', products);
        this.products = products.data;
    });
}

getProducts() {
    return this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:3200/api/products");
}

// Make getter of products
get Products() {
    return this.products;
}
```

**component**

*HTML*

```
<div *ngFor="let product of Products">
    // template here
</div>
```

*TS*

```
get Products() {
    return this.bcProductService.Products;
}
```

Comment: It didnt work for me. How confident are you that it should work?

Comment: It will, I'm 100% sure.

Comment: the constructors `console.log` from service does show the products (an array) but in the component, `Product` shows nothing

Comment: where you have `Provided` this service. I mean it should be shared between components if you want to access same instance among components.

Comment: `{{products|json}}` this will print the following `{ "closed": true, "_parent": null, "_parents": null, "_subscriptions": null, "syncErrorValue": null, "syncErrorThrown": false, "syncErrorThrowable": false, "isStopped": true, "destination": { "closed": true, "_parent": null, "_parents": null, "_subscriptions": null, "syncErrorValue": null, "syncErrorThrown": false, "syncErrorThrowable": false, "isStopped": true, "destination": { "closed": true }, "_parentSubscriber": null, "_context": null } }`

Comment: `Products` not `products` please check the `getter` name. It's capital `P`

Comment: Yes I saw that. still nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169612/discussion-between-anshuman-jaiswal-and-omar).

Comment: now how do I programmatically access `Products` from inside the component. I can console.log Products but I cannot console.log `Products.etc`. it says `undefined`

Comment: can you copy paste result of console.log(Products)?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010744/angular-5-programatic-access-to-observable-from-service-getter