# angular 5 programatic access to observable from service getter

Tags: angular

## Service

```
...
cart: any = {...}; //observable set in a subscription to and api response
get Cart() {
    return this.cart;
}
...
```

## Component

```
get Cart() { return this.bcCartService.Cart; }

constructor(
    private bcCartService: BcCartService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Cart: ",this.Cart); // see screenshot
    console.log("Cart: ",this.Cart.data); // "Cart:  undefined"
}
```

## Console Screenshots

[image]

## The Problem

I need to programmatically access `this.Cart` but i keep getting undefined or ts compile errors when i try to go any deeper for example  `this.Cart.data` returns undefined

Comment: paste HTML where you are accessing it.

Comment: it's working, you can check `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5wtcv`

Comment: `this.cart` is an observable. Its a result of an api call that I subscribe to.

Comment: You will have to async pipe if it's observable. Other solution is get data from api and subscribe in service assign the data in variable then in component use getter to access service's variable.

Comment: I have added answer you can refer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**service**

```
_cart:any;

fetchCartData(){
    this.http.get('/api/cart').subscribe (res => {this._cart = res});
}

get Cart() {
     return this._cart;
}
```

**component**

```
get Cart() {
    return this.service.Cart;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>{{Cart | json }}</p>
```

**Solution2**

**service**

```
getCartData() {
    return this.http.get('/api/cart');
}
```

**component**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.service.getCartData().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res); // here you will get desired data.
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes that works. But i need access in my component. try this `ngOnInit() {console.log(Cart)}` returns `undefined`

Comment: yes that could be because at the time you are accessing it data has not been fetched from API. If you want to something once data is received, subscribe the api in component.

Comment: @Omar I have added one more solution it will help you.

Comment: There may be no "simple" way to get what i want. I subscribe to the data and make the getter in the service because I need to reuse the data in several components. It reduces the api calls ==> with that in mind would you still recommend subscribing in the component?